# Remove member from consecutive groups with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample SQL table that has the following sample data:

```
Step  |  Member
---------------
 100  |  A
 100  |  B
 200  |  C
 200  |  A
 500  |  C
 500  |  A
 500  |  D
 800  |  D
 800  |  B
```

I would need users removed from all next consecutive steps.
As seen from the above table:

- member A is in consecutive steps 100, 200 and 500 and would need to be removed from 200 and 500.
- Same goes for member C - removed from 500, and D removed from 800.
- But user B should remain in 100 and 800 because they're not consecutive.

End result would be something like:

```
Step  |  Member
---------------
 100  |  A
 100  |  B
 200  |  C
 500  |  D
 800  |  B
```

Any way to do this with a `SQL` query?

Comment: Why c is removed from 500?

Comment: Because it also appears in 200. that's the catch, steps are not evenly distributed. They can be 100, 200, 500,... or 100, 400, 1000...

Comment: Logic is completely unclear. Now I will remove b800 because it also appears in 100. That `'because'` tells nothing to me. Why c is consecutive and b not?

Comment: B does not appear in steps 200 and 500 so it should remain in 800

Comment: What's your SQL Server release?

Comment: crazy sequence ever. Why B should appear on steps 200? You are saying B doesnt appear... but doesnt tell us what logic are you using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as(select *,
               dense_rank() over(order by step) dr,
               row_number() over(partition by member order by step) rn 
            from t)
select member, min(step) as step
from cte
group by member, dr - rn
```

Idea:

```
Step  |  Member  | dr  |  rn  |  dr - rn
----------------------------------------
 100  |  A          1      1       0
 100  |  B          1      1       0
 200  |  C          2      1       1
 200  |  A          2      2       0
 500  |  C          3      2       1
 500  |  A          3      3       0
 500  |  D          3      1       2
 800  |  D          4      2       2
 800  |  B          4      2       2
```

Grouping by last column and member gives you desired result I think. Can't check now in fiddle.

Fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c87a2/3

Comment: can you explain the sequence?

Comment: It doea produce the desired result. Will apply it to my query and verify the results

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, sequence is tricky. My brain exploded while I was figuring out. For example A. It appears in first group 100. It also appears in next group 200 and next group 500. So we are removing last 2. For B it appears in first group 100 but it does not appear in next group 200 not in  ext 500. It appears in 800 so we keep both. Imagine if there were one additional row 900 B we would kepp b100, b800 but delete b900 because b900 is the next group after 800...

Comment: You deserve upvote just for understanding that question.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around and looking at similar problems here's my go at it

```
SELECT step, member
FROM (
    SELECT s1.step, s1.member,
        (SELECT MAX(step) FROM @steps WHERE step < s1.step) as prevStep,
        (SELECT MAX(step) FROM @steps WHERE step < s1.step AND member = s1.member) as memberPrevStep
    FROM @steps as s1
) AS s2
WHERE memberPrevStep IS NULL OR prevStep <> memberPrevStep
```

Could this be an acceptable solution or is there a better way?